# PHPExcel generate a file with extension error on deployed server, but perfectly working on localhost

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

I had some routes that fetch data from a DataBase, open a template-file.xlsx and put that data, then, sent create a response to autodownloaded .xlsx file.

Worked at localhost never met any issues, but today deployed the project, and everything working fine, except that routes.

It generates me a result-xlsx file, but when I try to open it, it's treated like a xml and it's all in random symbols and so on.

I'm using PHPExcel bundle for Symfony, that has some shortcuts for PHPExcel library, but in fact is exactly the same.

I'm sure that I don't have problems in my code, but I'll provide it below :

My code :

```
   /**
   * @Route("/download-til/{id}", name="downloadTIL")
   * @Method({"GET","HEAD", "POST"})
   */
public function downloadTILAction(Request $request, $id, Loan $loan)
    {
      if($loan->getLine()->getDosier()->getUserId() != $this->getUser()){
          throw $this->createNotFoundException("Access denied"); }

        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Loan')
            ->find($id);


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $query1 = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
        FROM AppBundle:Charge p
        WHERE p.loanId = :loanId
        AND p.isActive = true
        ')->setParameter('loanId', $id);

        $query2 = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
        FROM AppBundle:Payment p
        WHERE p.loanId = :loanId
        ')->setParameter('loanId', $id);

        $query3 = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT d
        FROM AppBundle:Deferral d
        WHERE d.loanId = :loanId
        ')->setParameter('loanId', $id);

        $query4 = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
        FROM AppBundle:Charge p
        WHERE p.loanId = :loanId
        AND p.isActiveTEG = true
        ')->setParameter('loanId', $id);

        $query5 = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
        FROM AppBundle:Charge p
        WHERE p.loanId = :loanId
        ')->setParameter('loanId', $id);

        $calculator = new Calculator(
            $query->getDate(),
            $query->getCapital(),
            $query->getRate(),
            $query->getFrequency(),
            $query->getDuration(),
            $query->getType(),
            $query1->getArrayResult(),//charges with active SCH
            $query2->getArrayResult(),//forced payments
            $query3->getArrayResult(),//deferrals
            $query4->getArrayResult(),//charges with active BANK
            $query5->getArrayResult(),//get absolute all charges(active and inactive), to sort them in Calculator, and return to view
            $query->getForcedTIL()
        );

            $array = $calculator->getArray();
            $chargesArray = $calculator->getChargeTableArray();

          $dur = $query->getDuration();
        // ask the service for a Excel5
          $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
      $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($dir.'/OutputTIL.xlsx');

       $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("liuggio")
           ->setLastModifiedBy("Expertiseur")
           ->setTitle("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
           ->setSubject("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
           ->setDescription("Raport")
           ->setKeywords("office 2005 openxml php")
           ->setCategory("Analyse result file");

           $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
           ->setCellValue('B3', $query->getCapital())
           ->setCellValue('E3', $dur)
           ->setCellValue('H3', $array[0]['Date'])
           ->setCellValue('K3', $array[0]['Rate']/100)
           ->setCellValue('B12', $array[0]['Date'])
           ->setCellValue('I12', $array[$dur-1]['Date'])

           ->setCellValue('D12', $chargesArray[1000]['bankInterest1'])
           ->setCellValue('E12', $chargesArray[1000]['legalInterest1'])
           ->setCellValue('E13', $chargesArray[1000]['currentReparation1'])
           ->setCellValue('J12', $chargesArray[1000]['bankInterest2'])
           ->setCellValue('K12', $chargesArray[1000]['legalInterest2'])
           ->setCellValue('K13', $chargesArray[1000]['currentReparation2'])
           ->setCellValue('H15', $chargesArray[1000]['reparationGlobalPotential']);

             for($i = 20, $j = $dur; $j < $dur*2; $i++,$j++) {
                     $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                     ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $i-19)
                     ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $array[$i-20]['Date'])
                     ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $array[$i-20]['Capital'])
                     ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $array[$i-20]['Rate']/100)
                     ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $array[$i-20]['Interest'])
                     ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $array[$i-20]['Payment'])

                     ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $array[$j]['CapitalTIL'])
                     ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $array[$j]['RateTIL']/100)
                     ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $array[$j]['InterestTIL'])
                     ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $array[$j]['PaymentTIL'])
                     ;
                   }

      $BStyle = array(
        'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )));

      $highestRow = $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestDataRow();

      $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle("A20:K{$highestRow}")->applyFromArray($BStyle);

       $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Output TIL');
       // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet

        // create the writer
        $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');
        // create the response
        $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
        // adding headers
        $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            '4 Calcul au tx legal.xlsx'
        );
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
      $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
      $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
      $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

        return $response;       
    }//downloadTILAction
```

What can cause that error? Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note: what is the purpose of all those queries? Why can't you do `$loan->getPayments()`? You're type hinting `Loan` and then querying it?

But on topic: please share some information about your setup (OS, PHP version, composer). Try to save the file to disk and download it via FTP, to make sure it's the rendering process that fails.

Comment: Thank you for ur response, at my localhost I'm using Linux Ubuntu, PHP Version 5.6, my symfony project is using PHP 5.3. Composer... simple composer :D
That's the thing, I know about nothing about the hosting, cause I'm deploying it to my job's server, where is PHP 7.1, ubuntu as well. I installed all dependencies and modules, so it works, and the action that I am calling is works as well, just it is generating hieroglyphs instead of normal numbers and text.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Maybe that solves your problem. And you've got PHP 5.6 installed, but you're using 5.3? Don't understand that part. If you add this extra information to your question, it would be helpful for others too.

Comment: Yep, I have issues with my code, and I will fix it.
I didn't understand the part with "saving to disk and download it via FTP", for what? 
My action opens a template-excel file with some headers, and then introduce new values, and without saving it on site's project, it just returns it in auto-download response to user.
I have installed 5.6 PHP at my machine, but from composer, to symfony's 2.8 project, it requires PHP higher than 5.3

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to PHP 7.1 on your local machine? Developing an application on 5.6 and deploying to 7.1 is asking for problems.

Comment: In this case is no issues. And I can't see any relation in version PHP and the actual issue.

Comment: I do. There is a huge difference between 7.1 and 5.6. If the code is exactly the same, but your PHP version is completely different, that's very likely the problem. But have you tried my answer about Content-Type?

Answer (score 1):

Choose the right `Content-Type`:

> For BIFF .xls files
>
> ```
> application/vnd.ms-excel
> ```
>
> For Excel2007 and above .xlsx files
>
> ```
> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
> ```

To change this line:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
```

to this:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
```

### Bonus

*As a bonus, an answer for a question you didn't ask:*

Possibly without even knowing, you are using [type hinting](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-automatically) with the built-in Doctrine Converter. That makes these lines completely useless:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Loan')
        ->find($id);
```

Just use `$loan->getDate()` instead. And instead of `$query* = $em->createQuery()` you can use associations. If your [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) is correct (if not, fix it!) you can use `$loan->getPayments()`. You're using a very powerful and extensive framework, so use it's features!

Comment: Thank you for this information, for sure I will fix it.
Are you thinking that all issues came from the content-type?
I will try to change it to what you said as soon as I will have access to my working computer. Please, review my comment to previous answer. Thanks!